# How do I change the context of lambda?

Tags: ruby, lambda, metaprogramming

If you run the code below you get an error.

```
class C
  def self.filter_clause param_1
    puts param_1
    yield # context of this param is class B
  end

  def hi
    "hello"
  end
end

class B
  def self.filter(value, lambda)
    code = lambda { filter_clause(value, &lambda) }
    C.instance_exec(&code)
  end

  filter(:name, ->{ hi })
end
```

The error is

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `hi' for B:Class
from (pry):17:in `block in <class:B>'
```

From my understanding the reason for this is the lambda is running under the context of `class B`. So it can't find the method `def hi`. I can't figure out how to get it to run under the context of `class C`.

Essentially I want to be able to inject a method being called in another class that accepts an argument and a block.

For example:

`filter_clause("value", ->{ hi })`

Is this possible?

Not sure if I am making sense.

Comment: Where is this class A?

Comment: Sorry removed reference to A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. If you want the lambda(/block, really) to execute in the context of an instance of `C` (since `hi` is an instance method on C), then you'll need to instantiate it and then instance_exec the block on that new instance:

```
class C
  def self.filter_clause param_1, &block
    puts new.instance_exec &block
  end

  def hi
    "hello"
  end
end

class B
  def self.filter(value, lambda)
    code = lambda { filter_clause(value, &lambda) }
    C.instance_exec(&code)
  end

  filter(:name, ->{ hi })
end

# => hello
```

Comment: `instance_exec` inside `instance_exec`? Fun expected :D Regardless, this is valid Ruby.

Comment: There have two lambdas in play here, and they both have to be rebound. We aren't just rebinding the same lambda twice. The `code` lambda gets rebound to execute on `C`, and the anonymous lambda passed to `filter` gets rebound to execute on an instance of `C`.

Comment: True, but one of the contexts is unused anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I have marked this as the answer although it isn't exactly what I wanted. I didn't want to change the signature of C.filter. I have another higher level question going which is what I am actually trying to achieve. It was a bit difficult to explain everything in 1 question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819919/how-does-the-metaprogramming-of-scopes-work-in-rails

Comment: @Ryan-NealMes your other question is deleted, but it's not very clear. Can you provide a not-pseudocode example of what you actually are trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Are you opposed to passing the context into the block? If not, something like this would work:

```
class C
  def self.filter_clause param_1
    puts param_1
    yield self
  end

  def hi
    "hello"
  end
end

class B
  def self.filter(value, lambda)
    code = lambda { filter_clause(value, &lambda) }
    C.instance_exec(&code)
  end

  filter(:name, ->(klass){ klass.new.hi }) # "hello"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to have to specify the context in the calling of filter if possible. I have already managed to get a version of that working. It feels like it bloats the code. I was hoping somehow I could get it to infer the context. I could potentially update the context in the `def self.filter` method, but I am not sure how to change the context of the lambda in the `def self.filter`.